# Music player for Linux which remembers the playback position

Tags: ubuntu, music

I'm looking for a music player for my Ubuntu Karmic desktop. I need the following features:

1. supports multiple playlists
2. remembers the playback position (file and time) for *each* playlist
3. preferably, remembers playback position even when the process is killed
4. lets the user adjust playback speed, without changing the pitch

I don't care if it's a GUI or command-line player or it uses a client-server model.

I've tried Rhythmbox, which doesn't have features 2., 3. and 4.

Which player would you recommend?

Comment: That sounds more like a semi professional audio software than a musicplayer. but i am interested, too.

Comment: It does not sound like a professional player to me. Almost every Android audiobook player app (even free ones) have most of (or all of) these features. It sucks that most Linux players do not have them. I'm still looking for a solution for Linux...

Comment: Not an answer, but I checked Audacious: 1 True, 2 False, 3 True (with pkill), 4 True (through settings -> Plugins -> Effects -> Speed and Pitch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find such a player, I implemented one for my own use as a Python script, which supports playing `.m3u` files, and calls mplayer with the proper `-ss` value to resume playback where it left off last time. Get it from http://raw.github.com/pts/mplaylist/master/mplaylist (project page: http://github.com/pts/mplaylist).

Answer (score 5):

SMPlayer seems to meet most or all of your requirements (and more).

SMPlayer - Free Media Player for Windows and Linux with Youtube support - Official Site
http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/

1. supports multiple playlists **YES**
2. remembers the playback position(file and time) for each playlist **YES**
3. preferably, remembers playback position even when the process is killed **NOT SURE**
4. lets the user adjust playback speed, without changing the pitch **YES**

Comment: My experience so far is that smplayer does not remember the position. I start playing a track, then click the [x] to close the program. On restarting it, the position bar is at the beginning, and pressing 'play' starts the track from the beginning. How do you get your results?

Comment: I in fact have the "Remember settings for all files" and "Remember time position" checked. It seems to be of no use.

Comment: Ah! I had to find and uncheck the option "Play files from start" under Preferences > Playlist. Thanks.

Comment: Does this still work? For me, SMPlayer always starts the first file in the playlist, not the one I last played.

Comment: @Joschua Currently I am using DeaDBeeF and cmus as my music players. DeaDBeeF resumes the playlist where it left off. http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MountainX Thanks, though I was looking more for a solution for video players.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `mpv`
for me on ubuntu
`sudo apt install mpv`

then
`mpv --save-position-on-quit *`
This save all position for all file by obtaining md5

My alias( in .bashrc):

```
alias mpvsp='mpv --save-position-on-quit --osd-level 3 --osd-align-y bottom --osd-align-x right --osd-color 0/1/1  --osd-font-size 30'
```

#### Update

For new version, for each argument an equal sign (=) is needed

```
alias impv='mpv --speed=1.1 --save-position-on-quit --osd-level=3 --osd-align-y=bottom --osd-align-x=right --osd-color=0/1/1  --osd-font-size=30'
```

NOT support:
<s>3. preferably, remembers playback position even when the process is killed</s>

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `mpv`, I've checked it out. Per-file position is saved upon Q, Ctrl-C (SIGINT) and SIGTERM, and it's not saved (but completely lost) on kill -9 (SIGKILL).

Please note that your answer doesn't answer the question, because it misses requirement #1: *supports multiple playlists*.

Comment: okay, I understand your meaning, may be it would be the answer for someone else.  If you want I delete my answer, just tell, no problem ;)

Comment: It's fine to keep it, because it may inspire someone to find an `mpv`-based solution with playlist support.

Comment: +1 I tried all suggested answer, and this is the best choice by far - thank you!

Comment: For me your command doesn't work. 'Usage:   mpv [options] [url|path/]filename'.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko What version do you use? What OS? Or see its **doc** at https://mpv.io/manual/stable/

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri I use Fedora Core 29. I installed mpv 0.29.1 from dnf. In fact, I've already installed SMPlayer, and it's much easier for me than a console program (I don't need to read man to know the keys (though I use keyboard with other players, but it's still easier)).